# WIFCONTINUED not recognised

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system

I'm writing a C program and GCC doesn't recognise WIFCONTINUED. I've included the library that contains it (sys/wait.h) and checked that the library does exist on my machine.
My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "LineParser.h"

//Some code...
if(WIFCONTINUED(status)){

      temp->status = RUNNING;

}

//More code...
```

The error I get when I compile is:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘WIFCONTINUED’; did you mean ‘__W_CONTINUED’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                 else if(WIFCONTINUED(status)){
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                         __W_CONTINUED
undefined reference to `WIFCONTINUED'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem with WIFCONTINUED?

EDIT:
Here is some example(not my original program) that failes to compile with the same errros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv){

        int status;

        if(WIFCONTINUED(status)){


                 printf("Works");

         }

        return 0;
   }
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and my makefile is:

```
all: rep

rep: rep.o
         gcc -g -Wall -m32 rep.o -o rep

rep.o: rep.c
         gcc -g -Wall -m32 -ansi -c -o rep.o rep.c

.PHONY : clean
 clean :
      -rm -f *.o
```

Comment: what OS/libc are you compiling this on and how do you compile (i.e. compile command)?

Comment: If possible, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and include the errors from that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is the `-ansi` flag. It's [equivalent to `-std=c90`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) and `WIFCONTINUED` is not part of the C standard.

Most of the system programming headers you have included are from POSIX. So `-ansi` isn't going to help with anything at all. Just dropping the flag `-ansi` would be sufficient to fix this.